# Angular ui router undefined function in controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router, resolve

I have a ui route that looks like the following

```
.state('question', {
        url: '/question',
        templateUrl: 'views/templates/question.view.htm',
        controller: 'QuestionController',
        resolve: {
            questions_preload: function(Question) {
                return Question.query();
            }
        }
    });
```

The Question.query() function looks like

```
Question.query = function () {
            var deferred = $http.get(HATEOAS_URL);
            return SpringDataRestAdapter.processWithPromise(deferred).then(function (data) {
                Question.resources = data._resources("self");
                return _.map(data._embeddedItems, function (question) {
                    return new Question(question);
                });
            });
        };
```

and the controller that should have the questions preloaded at the start beings like this

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('QuestionController', function ($scope, Question) {

    $scope.questions = questions_preload;
```

Unfortunately while the Question.query() method runs correctly the questions_preload which I figured would house the array is undefined when the controller executes.

I believe it's something to do with the deferred in the query function? 
Would anyone have any idea?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject the `questions_preload` value into your controller:

```
angular.module('myapp')
.controller('QuestionController',
  function ($scope, Question, questions_preload) {
    ...
    $scope.questions = questions_preload;
```

As you had it you were simply accessing an undefined variable.

The use of a promise in `Question.query()` doesn't matter here as angular ui-router will wait until the promise has resolved before it instantiates your controller.

Comment: Sorry I did see that I hadn't injected that earlier and amended but still I just get

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: questions_preloadProvider <- questions_preload <- QuestionController

Thanks for the response though Duncan

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trying to instantiate the controller elsewhere? e.g. directly from your html. You should be able to inject that value when instantiated by ui-router but it wouldn't be available at other times. (Just guessing here, otherwise I can't see why you would get that error)

Comment: Awesome Duncan!! I had no idea that the ui.router was instantiating the controller and that the ng-controller I had was also instantiating another controller.

How do I mark this as the answer??

Comment: Ah my bad I had removed the 'return' before the _map in the service so the map containing the questions was being created but being lost because it wasn't being returned.

Works perfectly now! Thank you for your help Duncan.